# How to solve Kotlin typecast issue?

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, casting

I want to pass array of custom object through intent.

```
    val valuesToBeSent =  listOf(
            RSSSource("title", "someurl"),
            RSSSource("title2", "someurl")
    ).toTypedArray()

    val i = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
    i.putExtra("SOURCES", valuesToBeSent)
    startActivity(i)

    //ONSECOND ACTIVITY

    val rssSources = intent?.extras?.getSerializable("SOURCES") as? Array<RSSSource>
```

I could pass the values like this from one activity to another activity. But it gives following warning in android studio, when I try to typecast value. I converted list into typed array since, list couldn't be pass through intent as extras.

[image]

Also, even if I cast it ignoring warning I could access values of the array in second activity in devices supporting SDK > 21 but in devices supporting SDK 19 it crashes the app.

What is the proper way to send the array of custom objects through intent?

Comment: I don’t know how it works on 21 api and above! Cause kotlin list do not implement serializable and you probably want use Arraylist instead. So put arrayList in intent and thing should be fine

Comment: I am not sending list in intent but a TypedArray.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Typed array. But your question was 'What is the proper way to send the array of custom objects through intent?'. I shared my opinion. If you need to serialize - use ArrayList (or other Serializable entity).

And if you've get some strange crashes on KitKat it'll be nice to see details from it. I have never got such problems...

Answer (score 2):

You just need to put in Intent right data structure. Something that could be serialized. Use ArrayList, why not ? It serializes correctly and works like a sharm. If I could write code for test collection serialization via intent I would write something like this.

```
 fun testIntent() {
  val KEY = "key"
  val list = arrayListOf("one", "another")
  val intent = Intent().putExtra(KEY, list)
  val bundle = intent.getSerializableExtra(KEY) as? java.util.ArrayList<String> ?: emptyList<String>()

  assert(bundle[0] == "one")
}
```